# pandas rename column if contains string

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I would like to go through all the columns in a dataframe and rename (or map) columns if they contain certain strings.

For example: rename all columns that contain 'agriculture' with the string 'agri'

I'm thinking about using `rename` and `str.contains` but can't figure out how to combine them to achieve what i want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.replace.html) to process the columns first, and then re-assign the new columns back to the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A_agriculture': [1,2,3],
                   'B_agriculture': [11,22,33],
                   'C': [4,5,6]})
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('agriculture', 'agri')
print df
```

Output:

```
   A_agri  B_agri  C
0       1      11  4
1       2      22  5
2       3      33  6
```

Comment: ooo thanks yes that makes a lot of sense. do you know if i wanted to replace the whole string with `agri` rather than just `agriculture`?

Comment: The pattern specified in ``replace`` is regex, so you could do something like: ``replace('.*agriculture*', 'agri')``; however, that would cause the updated DataFrame to have two columns with the same name.

Comment: although now I am receiving an error: `raise error, v # invalid expression
error: nothing to repeat` it seems like it does not like the wildcards in the replace function

Comment: Did you forget the ``.`` (i.e. ``.*`` instead of ``*``) at the beginning?

Comment: mm thanks. what does the `.` do? when i throw it in i then receive `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`